# Multiply certain range of values in a data frame with a number

Tags: r, time-series

I have the following data frame:

```
Date<-c("2013-01-01 02:00:00","2013-01-02 02:00:00","2013-01-03 02:00:00","2013-01-01 02:00:00","2013-01-02 02:00:00","2013-01-03 02:00:00")
Parameter<-c("Par1","Par1","Par1","Par2","Par2","Par2")
conc<-c(1,4,3,2,6,5)
obs<-data.frame(Date,Parameter,conc)
obs$Date<-as.POSIXct(obs$Date)
obs$Parameter<-as.factor(obs$Parameter)
obs$conc<-as.numeric(obs$conc)
```

I will need to get the parameter values for the period 2.-3.01.2013 and multiply the conc value for only those dates by 5.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could create sequence of dates between two dates find out the row indices which overlap with them and then multiply those `conc` values with 5.

```
inds <- as.Date(obs$Date) %in% seq.Date(as.Date("2013-01-02"), 
                               as.Date("2013-01-03"), by = "day")
obs$conc[inds] <- obs$conc[inds] * 5

obs
#                 Date Parameter conc
#1 2013-01-01 02:00:00      Par1    1
#2 2013-01-02 02:00:00      Par1   20
#3 2013-01-03 02:00:00      Par1   15
#4 2013-01-01 02:00:00      Par2    2
#5 2013-01-02 02:00:00      Par2   30
#6 2013-01-03 02:00:00      Par2   25
```

Comment: @Rank Shah I modified your code a bit to be able to create a sequence not only by day but by hour: `inds <- as.POSIXct(obs$Date) %in% seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct("2013-01-02 02:00:00", tz="UTC"), 
                                        as.POSIXct("2013-01-03 02:00:00", tz="UTC"), by = "hour")`